# Bootstrap 4.5 Navbar on iPhone/iPad Collapse Button opens menu but closes immediately

Tags: ios, twitter-bootstrap

I have searched the web for this and cannot figure out it, some of the code is directly from the Bootstrap 4.5 site. The issue is that on my browser (both local and deployed to the server) my Navbar works fine. On my iPhone and iPad if I click the "hamburger" button, the menu displays and immediately closes.

My header includes:

```
<!-- Bootstrap core CSS (version 4.5) -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $Award_html_RootPath ?>css/bootstrap.css" type="text/css" />
```

My footer area includes:

```
<!-- CDN for jquery -- required for interactive parts of bootstrap and other code to function -->
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"
              integrity="sha256-QWo7LDvxbWT2tbbQ97B53yJnYU3WhH/C8ycbRAkjPDc="
              crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript, popper.js required for tooltips and such -->
      <script src="<?php echo $Award_html_RootPath; ?>jscode/popper.min.js"></script>
      <script src="<?php echo $Award_html_RootPath; ?>jscode/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

The Navbar definition looks like:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">

            <!-- the logo on left -->
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="<?php echo $Award_html_RootPath; ?>index.php">
               <img alt="Awards"
                    src="<?php echo $html_RootPath; ?>WebsiteImages/wk_heralds.png"
                    height="32px"
                    class="Logo" />
            </a>

            <!-- button when navbar collapses for smaller media like phones -->
            <button class="navbar-toggler"
                    type="button"
                    data-toggle="collapse"
                    data-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
                    aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
                    aria-expanded="false"
                    aria-label="Toggle navigation">
               <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>

            <!-- the actual menu -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
               <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                  <li class="nav-item">
                     <a class="nav-link"
                        style="color: #777 !important;"
                        href="<?php echo $Award_html_RootPath; ?>index.php" >Home
                     </a>
                  </li>
                  
                  <!-- dropdown -->
                  <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                     <a href="#"
                        class="nav-link dropdown-toggle"
                        data-toggle="dropdown"
                        role="button"
                        aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        Award Search Options<span class="caret"></span>
                     </a>
                     <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li class="dropdown-item"><a href="<?php echo $Award_html_RootPath; ?>namesearch.php">Name Search</a></li>
                        <div role="separator" class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                        <li class="dropdown-item"><a href="<?php echo $Award_html_RootPath; ?>last30days.php">Awards in Last Month</a></li>
                        <li class="dropdown-item"><a href="<?php echo $Award_html_RootPath; ?>awards_by_date.php">Awards by Date</a></li>
                        <li class="dropdown-item"><a href="<?php echo $Award_html_RootPath; ?>awarddescript.php">Award Descriptions by Region</a></li>
                        <div role="separator" class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                        <li class="dropdown-item"><a href="<?php echo $Award_html_RootPath; ?>awards_by_reign_start.php">Lists of Royalty with Links to Awards Given in Reign</a></li>
                        <li class="dropdown-item"><a href="<?php echo $Award_html_RootPath; ?>branchsearch.php">Awards Given to Residents of a Region/Branch or by Royals of Same</a></li>
                        <div role="separator" class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                        <li class="dropdown-item"><a href="<?php echo $Award_html_RootPath; ?>laureldetail.php">Find a Laurel in Your Art</a></li>
                        <div role="separator" class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                        <li class="dropdown-item"><a href="<?php echo $Award_html_RootPath; ?>precedence.php">Order of Precedence</a></li>
                        <div role="separator" class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                        <li class="dropdown-item"><a href="<?php echo $Award_html_RootPath; ?>full_list_to_txt.php">List to Text File <i>(For Mobile)</i></a></li>

                     </ul> <!-- / dropdown-menu -->
                  </li> <!-- / nav-item dropdown -->
<!-- there is more, but am truncating code -->
               </ul> <!-- /ul for menu -->
            </div><!--/ nav-collapse -->
         </nav>
```

As noted, in the browser it works, but on the phone and iPad it doesn't (clicking the button opens and closes the menu), and I am completely stumped. I have been trying this for a day, altering the code a bit at a time and re-uploading it, refreshing the page, and not seeing anything that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears to be specifically with Safari on iOS. Weirdly, on my iPad this eventually resolved (my iPad cannot upgrade to iOS 14.x, because it's an older device), and it seems to work, but on my iPhone SE, with iOS 14.1 or 14.2 (can't remember), the menu button acts as noted in the original post (tap it and the menu opens and rapidly closes). If I open the same page in Firefox or Chrome (downloaded from the app store), the page works (although some of the automatic Bootstrap resizing doesn't appear to be happening correctly on either browser). I think Bootstrap 4.5 has some serious issues that need to be addressed.